# write .conf file with nodejs

Tags: node.js, bash, nginx

Is it possible to write a `.conf` file with nodejs? I want to create a redirect file for my website(I'm using Nginx there) and I have a lot of URLs that I need to redirect. So I thought the best way to do this is to hit my API and write all redirects to a `.conf`-file.

So: Is this possible or maybe is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course, you can write files with fs. then you can symlink the config file to Nginx config folder. then restart the Nginx service. remember you must have permission to symlink to Nginx.

```
let config =` your config`;
fs.writeFile(
    `./test.conf`,
    config,
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      let symlinkToNginx = spawn("ln", [
        `./test.conf`,
        "/etc/nginx/sites-availables",
      ]);
      symlinkToNginx.stdout.on("data", async (data) => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
      });

      symlinkToNginx.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
      });
```